# Assigning one value from an input field to two model objects in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm writing a web app using ASP.NET Core with cshtml views. Is it possible to take a value from an input field in a form and assign it to multiple model objects?

I am currently using a view model that contains 3 properties: `Ad`, `Advertiser` and `Subscriber`. In one of the views I want to bind the value from one input field to two of my view model properties. A simple code example of what I want to do is shown below:

```
     <input asp-for="@Model.Advertiser.Address && @Model.Subscriber.Address" class="form-control" />
```

Is there a simple trick for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Binding in Blazor works like 1 UI control - 1 property.

You can create a facade property for your two properties, though.

Comment: OK Thanks! I will look it up!